# opt-out triggers "There was an error in your request"

Tags: civimail, opt-out

People who click on an opt-out URL in our civimail get an error screen like "Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment." The ReportError extension captures a backtrace that I stored on pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/m1ZUk16P). I verified that this error is coming from real humans trying to opt out, not from bots.

This part is confusing:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => fopen(api/v3/Country/Getfields.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
    [file] => /home/user/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/File.php
    [line] => 417
)
```

Because in fact there is no file at api/v3/Country/Getfields.php, trying to fopen it causes an error. Can anyone decipher this for me?

Edit: This is on Civicrm 5.36.1 and Wordpress 5.7.2.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you running?

Comment: Edited to add version.